# How to prove the MLE for Weibull distribution is biased or unbiased?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator, weibull-distribution

My attempt is like this:

Let $X \sim \text{Weibull}(\alpha, \lambda)$ be a random variable following a Weibull distribution with pdf

$fx(x; \lambda) = \begin{cases}
{\alpha}{\lambda^{-\alpha}} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-(x/\lambda)^\alpha} & x \ge 0\\
0 & x < 0\\
\end{cases}$

$\begin{align}
E(\widehat{\lambda}_{mle}) &= (\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} E(X_i^{\alpha})}{n})^{1/\alpha} \\
\text{Since we know } E(X^{\alpha}) &= \lambda^{\alpha} \cdot \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha}\right) \\
&= \lambda^{\alpha} \cdot \Gamma(2) \\
&= \lambda^{\alpha} \\
E(\widehat{\lambda}_{mle}) &= (E(X_i^{\alpha}))^{1/ \alpha} \\
&= \lambda \\
\text{Thus it's unbiased}
\end{align}$

Comment: Are you treating $\alpha$ as known? If so you should probably be stating that it's known somewhere.

Comment: @Glen_b is this related?

Comment: You err in commuting the expectation with the power.  Use Jensen's Inequality to show this induces a bias whenever $1/\alpha \ne 1.$

Comment: @whuber Actually I am not commuting here. I tried to get $E(X^\alpha)$, which I think is $\lambda^\alpha$. Then I just plug in the $E(X^\alpha)$.

Comment: As suggested by @whuber, using Jensen's inequality provides a proof of bias.  But if you are still skeptical, then while certainly not a proof you should consider some simulations that will convince you that $\hat{\lambda_{mle}}$ can be biased.  If you are assuming that $\alpha$ is known, try the following in R:  `x1 <- rweibull(1000000, 3, 4); x2 <- rweibull(1000000, 3, 4); lambda = ((x1^3+x2^3)/2)^(1/3); mean(lambda)`.  Typically you're going to get a mean of the maximum likelihood estimator of around 3.78 which is definitely less than 4.

Comment: What you write in your post is circular.  Don't you want to begin with $\hat\lambda = \left(\sum_i X_i^\alpha\right)^{1/\alpha}$?  In that case you are commuting the expectation operator and the $1/\alpha$ power in the first line of your analysis.

Comment: If you're going to post the same question simultaneously, you should give the link to the other post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556726/how-to-prove-the-mle-for-weibull-distribution-is-biased-or-unbiased. Otherwise if there's an answer or even a suggestion at the other post, you are wasting the time of the folks from whom you expect answers.